# Is a variable set as a string, a string literal?

Tags: php, string

I have a variable `$myVariable = "hello world"`. Is `$myVariable` a string literal?

I'm curious if variable is considered its own type, or if it can take on the type of whatever it evaluates to.

Comment: That's not what a type is.

Comment: Is the purpose of this question jargon tutoring, or did something else come up as programming woe?

Comment: You can use the variable for whatever you want.  PHP is a loosely typed language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `$myVariable` a string literal?

No, `"hello world"` is the [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). It is a [literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29) for a string.

> I'm curious if variable is considered its own type

No. Values have type, not variables. Variables refer to values.

Comment: Got it, thank you! (will accept when timer is up)

Answer (score 2):

No, then it becomes the value of a variable.

```
// string literal as input
myfunction("Hello, world!");

// variable as input
$myvar = "Hello, world!";
myfunction($myvar);
```

The `string literal` is just the quoted part, in this case `"Hello, world!"`

Comment: should the last one be `Hello, world!` not `"Hello, world!"` im not trying to be difficult, just clearing it up for myself

Comment: @Dagon [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) defines: "A string literal is the representation of a string value within the source code of a computer program." Because of that, the quotes are part of the literal.

Comment: ok i think i may just go back to being ignorant :-) `where "foo" is a string literal with value foo (the quotes are not part of the value).`

Comment: @Dagon `foo` is the value, `"foo"` is the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

A string literal is the representation of a string value within the source code of a computer program. Most often in modern languages this is a quoted sequence of characters, as in x = "foo", where "foo" is a string literal with value foo (the quotes are not part of the value).

First two lines from:
[String literal wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal)

So no in `$myVariable = "hello world"` the string literal is `"hello world"`

Answer (score 0):

The string literal is `Hello, world!` in your example not the variable

A string literal can be specified in four different ways:

single quoted

double quoted

heredoc syntax

nowdoc syntax

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: This does answer my question and thanks for the references Emilio :)

Answer (score 0):

`$myVariable` is a variable of type string, and `"hello world"` is a string literal, just like `$number` is a variable of type integer, while `5` is an integer literal, in `$number = 5;`

So, a variable assumes the type of it's contents. Run this to see what types PHP assumes for these literals:

```
$string = "hello world";
var_dump($string);

$number = 5;
var_dump($number);
```